# error in adding numbers : You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a number that is defined as 0, and an increase method that increases the number...

but when I use these it says

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

html :

```
<div id="app">
  {{ increase() }}
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
var application = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    number: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    increase: function() {
      this.number++
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you want to call the `increase` method on click? If yes then define it as `<div id="app" @click="increase">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the method `increase` in the component `template` causing a change in `data` and a rerender by `vue` to update which keeps repeating, the right way to do it is when an event occurs:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    number: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    increase: function() {
      this.number++
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increase">Increase</button>
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
</div>
```